# How to get changeset history from Item (from code)

Tags: c#, tfs

I try to get name of developer by project module with TFS.

So, i get module name (ex:MyCompany.Project.ProjectName)- and find some projectName like:MyCompany.Project.ProjectName.csproj.

```
 var items = _tfsClient.GetItems(pr.Name, RecursionType.Full);
 public ItemSet GetItems(String projectName, RecursionType recursionType)
    {
        try
        {
            return _version.GetItems(String.Format(@"$\{0}", projectName), recursionType);  
//(_version is VersionControlServer)
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Log(ex.Message, Logger.LogCategory.Error, Logger.LogPriority.High);
            _logger.Log(ex.StackTrace, Logger.LogCategory.Error, Logger.LogPriority.High);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Then,i find Item with target name.

```
  Item targetItem = FindItem(moduleName, itemsColl);
  var dir = GetFolder(targetItem);                
  dir = dir.Replace(@"\", @"/");
  Item targetDir = FindItem(dir, itemsColl,ItemType.Folder);
```

And find folder of it.
So, then find targetFolderItem of this folder.

But now, i have Item object of folder (and object of projectName item) and  need to get history of this folder: who changes it?

So, can you tell me how to do that?
Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by " who changes it?" in your second last line...If you want to get the history of a particular item you will have to use query. but i dont exactly get what you were trying to say..

Answer (score 0):

Is queryhistory method you are looking for? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb138960(v=vs.120).aspx